# How can I split an existing Debian package such that one of the new packages pre-depends on the other?

Tags: dependencies, debian

Sections [7.4](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html#s-conflicts) and [7.6.1](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html#s-replaces) of the Debian Policy Manual describe the proper method for splitting a Debian package in two.  However, I have a somewhat more complex situation.

I currently have two packages, at, say, version 1.2.3:

```
Package: foo-base

Package: foo-dbserver
Depends: foo-base (>= 1.2.3)
```

Initially, this relationsihp made sense, but over time, and somewhat by accident, elements of **foo-base** have come to depend on elements of **foo-dbserver**. Worse, the reality is that elemtns of **foo-base** *Pre-depend* on elements of **foo-dbserver**.  So what I want now is to split **foo-base** into **foo-essential** and **foo-base** as follows, for version 1.2.4:

```
Package: foo-essential
Replaces: foo-base (<< 1.2.3)
Breaks: foo-base (<< 1.2.3)

Package: foo-dbserver
Depends: foo-essential (>= 1.2.4)

Package: foo-base
Pre-Depends: foo-dbserver (>= 1.2.4)
```

These three packages install happily on a new installation, but they do not upgrade cleanly:

```
dpkg: regarding foo-base_1.2.4_all.deb containing foo-base, pre-dependency problem:
 foo-base pre-depends on foo-dbserver (>= 1.2.4)
  foo-dbserver latest configured version is 1.2.3
dpkg: error processing foo-base_1.2.4_all.deb (--install):
 pre-dependency problem - not installing foo-base
dpkg: regarding foo-essential_1.2.4_all.deb containing foo-essential:
 foo-essential breaks foo-base (<< 1.2.3)
  foo-base (version 1.2.3) is present and installed.
dpkg: error processing foo-essential_1.2.4_all.deb (--install):
 installing foo-essential would break foo-base, and
 deconfiguration is not permitted (--auto-deconfigure might help)
(Reading database ... 39107 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace foo-dbserver 1.2.3 (using foo-dbserver_1.2.4_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement foo-dbserver ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of foo-dbserver:
 foo-dbserver depends on foo-essential (>= 1.2.4); however:
  Package foo-essential is not installed.
dpkg: error processing foo-dbserver (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 foo-base_1.2.4_all.deb
 foo-essential_1.2.4_all.deb
 foo-dbserver
```

Is there a way to express this relationship properly, such that an upgrade will be possible? Would completely renaming foo-base to something else (and using the names **foo-essential**, **foo-dbserver**, **foo-base2**) be a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I found is to split the packages the other direction.  That is, to leave the original package name as the one being Pre-Depended upon, and use a new package name for the one doing the Pre-Depending.

```
Package: foo-base

Package: foo-dbserver
Depends: foo-essential (>= 1.2.4)

Package: foo-extra
Pre-Depends: foo-dbserver (>= 1.2.4)
Replaces: foo-base (<< 1.2.3)
Breaks: foo-base (<< 1.2.3)
```